# Google oauth2 service api key not valid

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I used Google_Oauth2 Service in github to login via google in my site 
But today we're a problem with the callback url address 
When identity is done

In the return address we encounter the following error

```
Message: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?key=%2A%2A%2A2A%2A: (400) API key not valid. Please pass the valid API key.
```

We have not changed anything before

secret key and api key is correct

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, when I tried to HTTP GET the profile info I was passing the `client_id` as the ***key*** URL parameter of the `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo` request but after sometime this month I was getting "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.".

Old Code:

```
$headers = ["Authorization: Bearer " . $tokenResp['access_token']];
$oauthInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents('oauth-credentials.json'), true);
$params = [
  "key" => $oauthInfo['web']['client_id']
];
$userInfo = HTTPGet('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo', $params, $headers);
```

I went to the google console for the same *project* I had created the oauth info, "Credentials" (left nav) clicked the blue "Create credential" button, picked "API Key" and used the key value provided there as the ***key*** URL parameter for the `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo` and it resolved my issue.

New Code (just changed the line):

```
  "key" => "AIz........................JWUM"
```

to use the API Key I generated instead of the ***client_id***